# NGX-FORMLY - Nested forms with multi-level navigation?

Tags: json, angular, forms, reactive, angular-formly

ngx-formly angular-form has example for multi-steps form and tabs form but I don't know how to do a multi-level (nested) form.  For example, the first level is multi-step and the second level is tabs.  Even better if it can be done with a side bar multi-level navigation menu.  Here is my form model should look like (only 2 level for simplicity, but could have more levels).

Could it be done with custom navigation field type or wrapper?  The multi-steps and tabs are not really angular-form field type or wrapper.

```
{
    "root": {
        "category1": { //<!-- First level navigation -->
            "UserName": "Test1",
            "Address": "110 My street",
            "CreateDate": "2018-09-14T00:00:00"
        },
        "category2": { //<!-- First level navigation -->
            "section1": { //<!-- Second level navigation -->
                "check1": "true",
                "check2": "false",
                "commentlist": {
                    "row": [{
                            "comment": "1.1"
                        },
                        {
                            "comment": "1.2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "photolist": {
                    "row": [{
                            "Photo1": "oqpNlRSsfwqqwqwq",
                            "caption1": "Flower",
                            "Photo2": "AnU5HPOP89z9aKKKGI//2Q==",
                            "caption2": "Bird"
                        },
                        {
                            "Photo1": "asasaassasas",
                            "caption1": "Flower",
                            "Photo2": "AnU5HPOP89z9aKKKGI//2Q==",
                            "caption2": "Bird"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "category3": { //<!-- First level navigation -->
            "section1": { //<!-- Second level navigation -->
                //<!-- fields -->
            },
            "section2": { //<!-- Second level navigation -->
                //<!-- fields -->
            },
            "section3": { //<!-- Second level navigation -->
                //<!-- fields -->
            }
        }
    }
}
```